# How to encrypt bucket or objects using aws.s3 and R?

Tags: r, amazon-s3, encryption

**Question**

I want to put and get objects from an S3 bucket. I want either the object or the s3 bucket to be encrypted so that others cannot read my objects. How can I do this?

**Problem**

I have read the aws.s3 documentation. There is a put/get/delete encryption method for buckets. However, it is unclear to me how this function can be used to secure my bucket so that only I can load/extract objects from the bucket.

**Code**

Here is some (pseudo)code I have been using trying to attempt this problem. I have tried the get_encryption type api with aws.s3, but not sure if that is the right approach.

```
library(datasets)

sample_data <- datasets::AirPassengers 


#How do I un-encrypt bucket or objects housed in the bucket? 

#Here is how I rrite the data to the bucket 
aws.s3::write_using(sample_data, 
                    FUN = "write.csv", 
                    object = "sample_data.csv", 
                    bucket = "my-bucket") 

#How do I un-encrypt bucket or objects housed in the bucket? 


#Here is how I read the code on the bucket
asw.s3::get_bucket_df(bucket = "my-bucket") 
aws.s3::s3read_using(read_csv, 
                     col_types = cols(.default = "c"), 
                     object = "sample_data.csv", 
                     bucket = "my-bucket")
```

**References**

I have consulted with the following references:

- [aws.s3 Documentation](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/aws.s3/aws.s3.pdf)
- [aws.s3 issues](https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3/issues)

Thanks kindly in advance for any comments or suggestions.